# Leaflet KNN to find nearest markers

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to find the nearest markers on a map of a specific location with [Leaflet-knn](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn)

`let nearest = leafletKnn(leafletGeoJson).nearest(L.latLng(38, -78), 5)`

the `leafletGeoJson` consists all positions of the markers I have set on the map before.

`nearest` returns an array of objects which have a `_leaflet_id` with which I want to select the markers on the map:

`map._layers[nearest[0]]` but it doesn't work. For some reason it does not return the `_leaflet_id` of the markers but new leaflet objects.

Am I using this wrong?

**Edit:**

```
var geoJson = []
for (let i in s) {
  let s = s[i],
  ll = L.latLng(s.Location[0], s.Location[1]),
  llArr = { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [s.Location[0], s.Location[1]] },

  geoJson.push(llArr)

  L.marker(ll, { icon: icon }).on('click', function (e) {
    // some stuffg
  }).addTo(map)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `.nearestLayer()` and `.nearest()` methods of the leaflet-knn index return a data structure containing a reference to the `L.Layer` containing the nearest point (i.e. a `L.Marker` or `L.Polyline`, depending on what is inside your geojson data), e.g.:

```
var geojsonlayer = L.geoJson(geojsondata).addTo(map);

searchIndex = leafletKnn(geojsonlayer);

map.on('click', function(ev){
  // Perform a KNN search with maximum 1 element in the result set, 
  // then pick the first result from the result set.
  var nearestResult = searchIndex.nearest(ev.latlng, 1)[0];

  // The result has 'lat' and 'lon' properties...
  console.log('nearest lat: ', nearestResult.lat);
  console.log('nearest lng: ', nearestResult.lon);

  // ... as well as a 'layer' property containing the reference to the `L.Layer`,
  // which we can do something with.
  nearestResult.layer.bindPopup("I'm nearest to where you clicked!").openPopup();

});
```

See a [working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/J2Uyr3MUwCUBpdoKyHYp?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for your example. So what should technically work is that I do `map.remove(nearestResult.layer)` and it will remove that particular marker from the map?

Comment: That should be `removeLayer`, though. Compare https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-removelayer with https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-remove

Comment: thanks. One question though, how would be the inverse, so to remove all layers but the nearest ones?

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, maybe including some premature optimization. I suggest you ask a new question about that, explaining your use case.

Comment: I see your point but `removeLayer` doesn't work either. Maybe I'm missing a step here but my geoJson consists of lat / lng of the markers I have set before. I will edit my question to show you

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: I edited my question to show you. It consists of all thats needed